# Python to Pyspark Regex: Converting Strings to list

Tags: regex, pandas, pyspark

My code takes a string and extract elements within it to create a list.

Here is an example a string:

```
'["A","B"]'
```

Here is the python code:

```
df[column + '_upd'] = df[column].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',x.lower()))
```

This results in a list that includes "A" and "B".

I'm brand new to pyspark and am a bit lost on how to do this. Ive seen people use `regexp_extract` but that doesn't quite apply to this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a pandas frame or pyspark?

Comment: its code in pandas that i need to transfer to pyspark

Comment: Is the question basically "how do I convert a stringified list to a list"? If so, `ast.literal_eval(s)` is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`regexp_replace`** and **`split`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("new_col", F.split(F.regexp_replace("col", '\[|]| |"', ''),",")).show()

#+---------+-------+
#|      col|new_col|
#+---------+-------+
#|["A","B"]| [A, B]|
#+---------+-------+

#schema
 #root
 #|-- col: string (nullable = true)
 #|-- new_col: array (nullable = true)
 #|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```